# Javascript stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

It seems that Javascript has stopped working for a website I am building.
[Here](http://southernvoiceanddata.co.uk/) is a link to the site in question.
I'd like to clarify, as per my last experience here, that the link is there for pure reference. This isn't some form of advert. If I wanted to advertise, I'd certainly not open on an issue. that makes no sense.

The problem is the Testimonials. they aren't showing up at all!

It should look like [This](http://tinyurl.com/pm7au5j)
However i can't get it to work on the main site. It was working just a few days ago, but it's just, stopped since.

I think that the issue is with jQuery not loading, though it is present in the header. It's also worth noting, that they use Wordpress. hate the thing. static websites are so much easier to troubleshoot!

Comment: First thing to do to debug JavaScript: check the console. You have an error.

Comment: How would I do that? the debug window in Firefox doesn't seem to catch anything!

Comment: Normally it's the F12 key. There may be a 'console' tab you need to click on.

Comment: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: turns out the issue was with another edit I had made with a different javascript. fixed it now! still, thanks for your help! it was F12, but I still saw no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sliding-footer.js`, there is an error. The line

```
var original_position_offset = $('#BottomBarSlider').offset();
```

sets `original_position_offset` to undefined, since `$('#BottomBarSlider')` is not found. Which in turn throws the `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined error` when trying to access `original_position_offset.top`.

That's because element `#BottomBarSlider` is commented out inside HTML. Find this code in your html

```
<!--<div id="BottomBarSlider">
<div id="BottomBar">
...
</div>
</div>/-->
```

and remove `<!--` and `/-->`.

Comment: AAAH, that makes sense. I had to edit it out due to my client not wanting it. this explains the issue. All fixed now! thanks a lot! ^^